# How to handle ethernet frames in ns3

Tags: ns-3

I know there is some kind of callback procedure.I just want to tell to all net devices that every time something comes from ethernet I want to handle it myself.I also want to be able to send ethernet frames myself through that code.

Answer (score 0):

ns3::Node::RegisterProtocolHandler is your friend.

See the documentation: http://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.17/doxygen/classns3_1_1_node.html#af713f0e7ea5c49b4fa0b3613405c45fa